# Architecture Best Practice: Rails and Mobile/Web App

Tags: android, iphone, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mobile

I am having a browser-oriented web app build on Rails (3.1). I want to make some features of the web app available on mobile devices, too.

Besides...

***1.) Building native apps for each vendor of devices and interacting with my rails web app using JSON/XML***, ...

I am thinking about reusing as much as business logic already implemented in my rails app by reusing controllers/models and add some new views targeted to mobile devices (in terms of screen size and the like...).

With this approach, I see two alternatives:

***2.) Let the end user access the part of the rails app targeted to mobile devices in the mobile browser.***

***3.) Set up a native mobile app wrapper, e.g. using PhoneGap, and refer to the same part of the rails app used for 2.).***

The advantage of 3.) is that I can reuse business logic of my rails web app and having a "phantom" native app for mobile devices at the same time. (I used the term "phantom" because besides the wrapper, it's not really native, this approach actually just mimics a native app.)

**Question 1: Are there any other alternatives besides 1.) to 3.) ?**

Regarding 3.)

**Question 2: Does Apple accept this kind of apps (which fetch large portions remotely) to be uploaded to the app store?**

-> I would be surprised if it is so, because it would allow one to change large parts of the app without the notice of Apple.

**Question 3: From an architectural/technical point of view, is it recommended to remotely fetch prerenderd html/js to be executed in a "phantom" native mobile app build on top of e.g. PhoneGap?**

-> Wouldn't it be better to set up an independent client app within the native mobile app (maybe using backbone.js), keeping all html, css, js locally within the mobile app, and communicate with the backend using JSON/XML or whatever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a good question and I've recently come across similar difficulties.  I've ended up using (Q3) vaadin with touchkit.  Fine if you're doing free but a bit expensive if you're doing commercial (although then you can probably afford it).  I realise this doesn't relate to rails but still, I'm assuming the main point of the question was should I build native apps which use web services / middleware or go for pure web apps.

RE (Q2), during my trawl of this current technology, I did read a few articles suggesting that apple are not allowing the web app style.  As in, app which simply masks browser window loading remote web app.  Essentially, I think where apple are concerned, you'd need to have the functionality tied down to what they agreed to.  This doesn't really affect web apps though as you can surely just access them directly from the browser.

RE (Q1), the only alternatives I can see would be different middleware (e.g. MQ, SOAP etc).